# Coregraphics shape to fit in defined view

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am drawing shapes from a JSON using Coregraphics and the co-ordinates span from -ve to +ve axis. I am able to draw it properly using translation, but as my co-ordinates are pretty large, the drawing goes out of bounds of the view. is there a way to shrink and fit the drawing to the view bounds? I tried some scaling but didn't work. ( I cant use an image context as it will become blurr when zoomed, I am trying to get some vector).

Please find below the sample project

[DrawShapes from JSON](https://github.com/anoop4real/DrawShapeFromJSON)

In the shapes.json I have points like below and the points 500,....570 are drawn out of bounds, I want to fit the entire drawing with in the view bounds after the drawing is completed.

```
                      "X": -200.07484,
                      "Y": 50.60354
                      },
                      {
                      "X": -500.07484,
                      "Y": 400.95078
                      },
                      {
                      "X": 570.77671,
                      "Y": 400.95078
                      },
                      {
                      "X": 570.77671,
                      "Y": 100.70688
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After a lot of trials, I am finally able to fix the problem. I got a nice utility from [MMScalableVectorView](https://github.com/misterwell/MMScalableVectorView), where in which there was a method to adjust the content mode according to the entire drawing size and the actual view size.

More details: [MMScalableVectorView Site](http://michaelmaxwell.info/2013/12/13/using-vector-graphics-on-ios/)

I am not posting the code here as it is his code. Look for the below method in the code

```
- (void)applyCTMTransformsForContext:(CGContextRef)context frame:(CGRect)frame
```

I have updated my code which now fits according to the graphic size.